# How to notify client of std::iostream that there is no more data

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a client that passes an iostream to my API, which writes data to it as it arrives over TCP. I'm assuming that the client can continue to make blocking calls to the stream until the TCP data is complete. How do I signify to the client that there is no more data, preferably without a delimiter in the stream? Have I misunderstood streaming with this context? Is there a better way (eg calling back each time a new write occurs into the stream)?

Comment: close the stream, caller should get eof

Comment: Set the `eof` bit, perhaps? (I'm not sure how general a solution this is.)

Comment: @pm100 iostreams don't have a close member function

Comment: Apparently the eof "is set by all standard input operations when the End-of-File is reached in the sequence associated with the stream.". This seems to imply that the End-of-File must somehow be signified...

Comment: Setting EOF only makes sense when reading from a stream, not when writing to a stream.  The API would not need to signal EOF, it would simply stop writing to the stream.  The client would then get EOF when it tries to read past the end the stream and there is no more data to read.  This sounds more like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). I would suggest having the API provide a custom `std::basic_streambuf` class that can be attached to a standard `std::istream`. The class can then return TCP data as needed and report EOF when the stream tries to read when no more data is available.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for your comment and yes it could be an xy problem. Your first three sentences: I had considered that but say there is a delay in the middle of the tcp transmission, then the client will hit the eof prematurely. 

I will consider your suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: I am thinking that the solution here is not for the client to wait outside the API for the data. Rather to overload the << operator and to handle the data there, or wait until all of the data is compete (notified via callback) and then use the complete data in the stream buffers.